# android application crashes as I pass string to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

so here is another basic problem i'm having...my application crashes as i try to pass a string to another activity. i have tried a few ways but in vain. here's the code

Main Activity named Main.java

```
package com.ammad.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    Button b1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                String myScore = "testing";
                basket.putString("key", myScore);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
                intent.putExtras(basket);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Second class to which the data is passes named Second.java

```
package com.ammad.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity{

    TextView tv;
    String getScore;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRes);
        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        getScore = gotBasket.getString("key");
        tv.setText(getScore);
    }

}
```

and finally the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ammad.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sec"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ammad.test.SECS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output for the crash?

Comment: "my application crashes" is rather vague. Could you provide the stack trace of the error as printed out in LogCat? That should tell you exactly what's going wrong where and when.

Comment: Rename android:name=".Sec" to android:name=".Second" in your manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me your second activity is declared wrong in the manifest, as .Sec not .Second as would be expected - the log is probably showing a exception because the intent was invalid.